# Using variable that was defined inside a for loop

Tags: c, loops

I'm trying to define a 2D array inside a for loop. This is what it looks like:

```
for (){
   ...
   double x[y][z];
   ...
}
```

Then I call a function:

```
abc(x)
```

...and I'm getting this error:

```
error: 'x' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Answer (score 0):

A variable declared inside a `for` loop has its scope limited to the `for` loop and cannot be accessed outside of the `for` loop.

If you need to access the variable outside the `for` loop, you should declare it outside the `for` loop.

Comment: ok buy im getting the y and z values inside of the for loop, and im also using x after i declare it inside the for loop

Comment: You can declare the variable before the loop then set its values inside the loop.

Comment: both y and z are declared outside of the loop but are equal to 0, i want to define x after i get the value to y and z

Comment: If you post some more snippet of your code then it will help us to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass  `x` to your function `abc` only within the scope of `for` loop as `x` has block scope.
A variable with block scope can only be accessed inside that block. Beyond its scope it is invisible to other.

Comment: im editing the data inside of x within the for loop and i want to call abc only after the for loop is finished

Comment: Then declare `x` outside the `for` loop.